# Wagtail multisite on same domain

Tags: django, wagtail, multisite

I need to create a multisite configuration that let me use the same domain for different sites.

Some examples of what URLs I need to achieve:

```
subdomain.example.com  (Home for all sites)
|
---subdomain.example.com/common-page/  (Common page for all sites)
|
---subdomain.example.com/common-page-2/  (Common page for all sites)
|
--- subdomain.example.com/news/  (News from all sites)
|
--- subdomain.example.com/site-1/  (Redirects to Home subdomain.example.com)
|
--- subdomain.example.com/site-2/  (Redirects to Home subdomain.example.com)
|
--- subdomain.example.com/site-1/news/  (Site 1 news)
|
--- subdomain.example.com/site-3/news/  (Site 3 news)
|
--- subdomain.example.com/site-1/contact/  (Contact form site 1)
|
--- subdomain.example.com/site-3/contact/  (Contact form site 3)
```

I could create this structure on just one site, but it would then be a pain to manage it on the wagtail admin.

Comment: In Wagtail's terminology, sites and domains are exactly the same thing, so "multiple sites on the same domain" doesn't make sense. What *exactly* do you want Wagtail to do here which is different from a single-site installation? (Bear in mind that Wagtail will always show all your pages as a single tree, regardless of how many sites / domains you have configured.)

Comment: The difference from a single site installation is that every site have their own contact form, news and events. Right now I have the 3 sites configured and explorer tree shows me the 3 sites making it much easier to manage, but the pages arent accesible (error 404) on 2 of the sites

Comment: OK, let me rephrase my question: what's stopping you from creating the pages you want, as children of the homepage, so that their position in the page tree matches the URLs that you want?

Comment: The easier site management is the only thing that is stopping me creating just 1 site (3 sites with diferent news/events vs 1 site with 3 subpages news/events). But it seems is rather a small user experience improvement for the effort needed on the backend to achieve this as I intended to. Anyway, thanks gasman for making this clearer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Answering an old question for future enquirers.
[@gasman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1853523/gasman) has nailed the issue with this ask in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468577/wagtail-multisite-on-same-domain#comment77899296_45468577) above:

> In Wagtail's terminology, sites and domains are exactly the same
> thing, so "multiple sites on the same domain" doesn't make sense.

However, I was able to work around this using the following steps.

I needed this kind of arrangement so that *different* site-wide settings could be used for [mainsite.com](http://#) and [mainsite.com/subsite](http://#) (example names).

While I can always enforce different settings for different parts of my website in the code I've written, I wanted this to work for third-party packages as well such as `wagtailmenus` etc.

E.g. I wanted the menu-items for all pages on [mysite.com](http://#) to be different from those for all pages under and including [mainsite.com/subsite](http://#).

Note that this is a crude approach, and there can be unforeseen issues with this. But, so far, it has worked fine for me.

1. Create a new site in Wagtail admin for your *subsite*.
   Use the same `hostname` as was used for the *mainsite*, but add a dot in the end for satisfying uniqueness. We'll not use this `hostname` anyway.
   Also, use the same root page as `mainsite`'s. This is for generating the URLs correctly.
2. Create a small middleware:

   ```
   if request.path.startswith('/subsite'):
       # find subsite and mainsite using Site.objects.filter(site_name='') queries
       subsite.hostname = mainsite.hostname
       request._wagtail_site = subsite
   ```

   This will make sure that all requests coming to the subsite get their specific `_wagtail_site` attribute but with the correct `hostname`. This will let your code and all other code in third-party packages to determine the site as *subsite*. But, if a third-party package uses Django's `site` instead of Wagtail's `Site`, I'm not sure if this will still work.
3. Generally, you would not want the *subsite* to be set as default website. To enforce this, include the following in any of your apps' `admin.py` (I added some extra validations as well):

   ```
   def clean_subsite(self):
       instance = self
       if instance.site_name != 'Subsite': return
       super(Site, self).clean()
       if instance.is_default_site:
           raise ValidationError({'is_default_site': ["'Subsite' cannot be made the default website."]})

       mainsite = Site.objects.filter(site_name='Mainsite').first()
       if not mainsite:
           raise ValidationError({'hostname': ["'Mainsite' must exist before saving 'Subsite'."]})

       if instance.hostname != (mainsite.hostname + '.'):
           raise ValidationError({'hostname': ["Hostname for Subsite is just a placeholder (Subsite uses the same domain as Mainsite does)." +
           " Use the Mainsite's hostname with a '.' as suffix for satisfying uniqueness constraint."]})

   from wagtail.core.models import Site
   Site.add_to_class("clean", clean_subsite)
   ```

   As the `Site` filter queries above are using `site_name=''`, do not change the names of *Mainsite* and *Subsite* in the Admin (without modifying these queries in the code).
4. Lastly, be warned that the query `Page.objects.in_site()` will work incorrectly for both `mainsite` and `subsite`.
   Either do not use `in_site()`, or override it.
   This function uses:

   ```
   self.descendant_of(site.root_page, inclusive=True)
   ```

   For mainsite, we need to exclude the descendants of `subsite`'s root page.
   For subsite, we need to include only the descendants of `subsite`'s root page.